# :disabled field not working in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, fields-for

I'm trying to add a disabled drop-down box to my table, which I will eventually make conditional.
However, disabled doesn't seem to be added to the line when it is run.

If I inspect the element in the page, manually adding disabled works, but it is not being added at run-time.

```
= f.fields_for(:targets, qualification.target_for(@grandfather.user)) do |builder|
  %tr
    %td
      = builder.select :completed, qualification.level_options.map{|o| [o,o]}, :disabled => "disabled"
      = builder.hidden_field :qualification_id, :value => qualification.id
      = builder.hidden_field :id
```

Comment: In `:disabled => "disabled"`, the value `"disabled"` needs to be the value of one of the `<option>`s of the select - i.e `qualification.level_options` should have a element called `disabled`. `:disabled` is not used for disabling the entire HTML select element, but rather for marking a `<option>` element as disabled.

Comment: Zabba, I'm not following you entirely. Can you clarify a bit, isn't :disabled => 'disabled' an HTML5 feature?

Comment: I think you're referring to having "disabled" be an option of the drop-down box.

However, I'm looking to disable the entire dropdown box, using the disabled: "disabled" feature, so that you cannot select an option from the box.
The level_options already contains the options that are available for selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the API for Rails' [Form Helper API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

It was adding `:disabled => "disabled"` to the options, instead of the html_options.  This is the code to use instead (notice the empty hash for the options parameter):

```
builder.select(:completed, qualification.level_options.map{|o| [o,o]}, {}, {:disabled => "disabled"})
```

Comment: Its better to use `:readonly => true` instead of `:disabled => "disabled"`. As the field with `:disabled => "disabled"` with not include in parameters for controller